# What is "com.samsung.android.dqagent_SA_SDK" user certificate? Is it safe?

Tags: certificates

My user certificates has the following: **com.samsung.android.dqagent_SA_SDK**.

It seems so strange, it looks like someone put it on there. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

From the name **com.samsung.android.dqagent**_SA_SDK, looks like the certificate is installed and used by [DQA](https://knowledge.protektoid.com/apps/com.samsung.android.dqagent/d8aa10a3047db6f75d988777a0f91cfd7904e002f3404cd256db95174f674c09) (also known as [Device Quality Agent](https://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-issues-urgent-update-fix-device-quality-agent-error)), a Samsung system app.

From some reports (in [German](https://www.android-hilfe.de/forum/samsung-galaxy-s8-s8-g950f-g955f.3023/bestimmte-apps-kommen-nicht-mehr-ins-internet-https-problem.890663.html) and [Russian](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=904540&st=2260)), the certificate will automatically be reinstalled if it's removed, presumably by the app itself, since it also contains the certificate (from the report of [reverse.it](https://www.reverse.it/sample/df4285d0342bc7aace9de10ffe397a5b6f66b9db9d52c900f4087c556c9404b1?environmentId=200))

While I cannot certainly determine if it's safe or not, at least it's related to Samsung's own system app, so the possibility of a rogue certificate is lower (though not 0%). However, looks like you can [disable the app without any side effects](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s8+/help/s8-debloat-list-t3703985).